# Beckhoff PLC with pro-face HMI, change between displays

Tags: ads, st

We have recently started to work with Beckhoff PLCs in combination with pro-face HMIs. The communication goes over ADS. PLC and HMI exchange information using certain variables.

On the UI of the HMI I can switch between several screens by pressing on on-screen buttons. I can open test page for IO, test page for motors and a general settings menu.

[image]
There is this one thing which we haven't been able to figure out.

It is standard for all our machines to start with displaying our regular boot display. Here the user interface tells you to press the physical green start button which powers on the main relay and main air valve. As soon as air pressure is detected, the main menu should load.

I want to make use of a variable on the PLC to let the proface switch between displays (So without touching the HMI)

Provided that it is possible at all, how does one do this?

The pro-face is programmed with with the program GP-Pro EX.

Answer (score 0):

I've never programmed ProFace HMI, but I found this help on the ProFace website, I'm not sure if it corresponds exactly to your HMI model and version, despite the program's name being GP-Pro EX as mentioned, I believe it should provide you with some help.

[Pro-Face Help - GP-Pro EX v4.0](http://www.pro-face.com/otasuke/files/manual/gpproex/new/refer/gpproex.htm)

The link will not take you directly to the page, so click on "Content" and then search for "Displaying and Changing Screens":

[image: Help from GP-Pro EX]